# Natural embedding of a real vector space $V$ into $V_\Bbb{C}=V\otimes\Bbb{C}$ is injective

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, lie-algebras, tensor-products

Let $V$ be a real vector space and $V_\Bbb{C}=V\otimes_\Bbb{R} \Bbb{C}$ denotes the complexification. I want to identify $V$ as a real vector subspace of $V_\Bbb{C}$. I define the natural embedding map $v\mapsto v\otimes 1$ which is $\Bbb{R}$ linear from $V$ to $V_\Bbb{C}$. But I cannot show this to be injective i.e. $v\otimes 1=0 $ implies $v=0$. Maybe I'm missing something very silly.

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: You can identify $V_{\Bbb C}$ with $V^2$ where $(a+ib)(v,w)=(av-bw,aw+bv)$.

Comment: Yes I can map $(v,w)$ to $v\otimes 1+w\otimes i$. But I can prove this is onto. And for finite dimensional $V$, it is hence injective as well (as both of them has same dimension). But for infinite dimensional $V$ how to prove this map is injective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general injectivity and tensor products of modules is quite tricky. But with vector spaces, everything works out fine (because they are free, and therefore flat).

Actually, if $V$ and $W$ are two vector spaces over a field $K$, then $v\otimes w=0\in V\otimes_K W$ if and only if either $v$ or $w$ is zero.

You can show this by extending $v$ (resp. $w$) to a basis $(e_i)$ (resp. $(f_j)$) of $V$ (resp. $W$), if they are both non-zero. Then $v\otimes w=e_1\otimes f_1$, but you can show that $(e_i\otimes f_j)$ is a basis of $V\otimes_K W$, so in particular these tensors are definitely not zero.

Try to show that $(e_i\otimes f_j)$ is indeed a basis!